# Strange decimals are added to result

Tags: c#, double, decimal, multiplication

C# adds a decimal at the end in the result, my code:

```
public static double CalcCompoundedInterest()
{
    return (1.1 * 1.1);
}
```

Result: 1.2100000000000002

Does someone have a clue why this happens?

Comment: This issue is called floating point error and exists in all float point arithmetic. To avoid this issue (especially when dealing with variables reflecting money) languages like C# provide a fixed point type like `decimal`

Answer (score 5):

This is not a C# problem, this is the way computers work when they handle decimal values.

You see, 1.1 is stored as a float, which is encoded in binary using the [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) standard. Most decimals numbers are not possible to store without adding a very small error to them.